# Paypal Payments (Authorization & Capture) not returning Authorization ID

Tags: api, paypal, authorization, capture

According to [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/) the `paypal` payment method should be able to do Authorization & Capture just fine. The following excerpt under the **PayPal authorizations** excerpt specifically states how to go about it:

> First get payment approval and execute the payment as you normally would do for a PayPal payment. Once you successfully execute on the payment authorization, PayPal responds with a new set of HATEOAS links, including a capture link that you use to capture the payment.

So if im following correctly the flow for doing Authorize & Capture is as follows:

1. Create a Payment
2. Redirect User to HATEOAS link `approval_url` to get them to sign into paypal.
3. Be returned to success (or cancel, but not in this example) link.
4. Get the Payment to see what's changed, get the shipping address / etc....
5. Let the customer review the details
6. `Execute` The Payment to commit to the hold on funds.

   - At this point an AuthorizationID / HATEOAS Link should hold information about the authorization.
7. Some time later use the authorization ID to Capture, and *voila*, we're done.

Now this is all fine and dandy, but in my tests on the sandbox environment I'm having trouble retrieving the authorization ID **anywhere**.

Here's my HATEOAS Links I receive from my `Execute` Step:

[image: Payment HATEOAS Links]

As you can see, only the `self` reference is returned, according to the documentation there should be one `capture` link at the least that should have the authorizationID in it.

Also, nowhere in the response body is any authorization ID. However, If I look at the payment in my sandbox paypal dashboard:

[image: List]

And once I drill down into it:

[image: Details]

Sure enough if I call the `Authorization.Capture` API call against `8B633793L37511009` it captures as you would expect. However I can't find a programmatic way to determine this number.

---

How am I supposed to store the authorization number so my tooling can capture later when our business conditions have been met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the beggining, when you create the payment with intent `authorize` you should be getting an authorization object within the response. This object has the id you need for the capture later.

Check [this blog post](http://whyidentity.blogspot.com/2013/06/authcapture-and-more-w-paypal-restful.html) to see if you're missing something fundamental in the picture.

I followed the tutorial and executed the sample requests via curl. As you can see, I got the authorization id under `transactions->related resources->authorization->id`

[image: screenshot of paypal authorization object]

Then I used the id in the URL and successfully captured the payment.

Hope this helps, if it doesn't, please elaborate and maybe I will be able to help you further. Good luck!

Comment: That'll teach me to not look at the actual output. The prototype i was using had the related_resources all collapsed off to the side, so I didn't even see the entry!